# How to catch AJAX WebMethod errors in global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, error-handling, error-logging, webmethod

I'm using the common practice of catching errors in global.asax in my ASP.net application.  In global.asax, I have a function `Application_Error` that logs the errors to the database.

This works very well to log errors that occur when the user requests a page.

However, this does nothing to help when an asynchronous method (a method decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute) called from the client-side throws an exception.  The exception simply bubbles up and may be returned to the client-side code, but I would like to have the error handling code run on the server automatically similar to how page errors are logged in global.asax.

How do I accomplish this?  One way would be to wrap every single asynchronous method with try-catch, but this doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create an ASP.NET [output filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) that intercepts and logs WebMethod exceptions sent by ASP.NET to the client. Here's the basic idea:

1. Create a subclass of Stream that captures the content of the response.
2. When the stream is closed, check whether the response has a 500 status code as well as a `"jsonerror: true"` header. If so, the response contains a WebMethod exception; log the exception.
3. In Global.Application_PostMapRequestHandler, install an instance of this class as the output filter for JSON requests.

For complete source code, see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222240/1127114).

Answer (score -2):

[How to create a global exception handler for a Web Service](http://geekswithblogs.net/pavelka/archive/2005/09/05/HowToCreateAGlobalExceptionHandlerForAWebService.aspx)

Comment: That approach does not appear to be valid for calling WebMethods via AJAX GET/POST, only for SOAP webservice calls.