# Any way to handle Ajax Errors globally on asp net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, logging, error-handling, webforms

I am looking for a way to log ajax errors globally. I have already read numerous ways but none of them worked. The problem is that when an error occured in ajax requests it gets handled by the `RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall` and never triggers `Application_Error`.

It is well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222240/5495961) by @Michael Liu .

The problem with his answer is that there is no way to get the actual exception and log it if you have `customErrors` option set to On in webconfig.

Note that i don't want to return stack traces to javascript or anything like that. Also the app is very old and big and i am not able to change the entire system of how soap or ajax or logging works as it would be a high risk of breaking the app.

Is there any way to catch and log these exceptions globally?

Thanks in advance.